# How to make individual GetxControllers for reusable widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am trying to replace the use of Stateful widget with Getx. Most cases, I do not need it, however, when I am trying to create a list of cards widget, I find it hard to not to use the Stateful widget.

```
Obx(() {
  getxA.updateA(name);
  return Text(getxA.a());
})

RxString a = 'aaa'.obs;

updateA(String name) {
  a(name);
}
```

When I have this `Obx() - Text Widget` inside the List Widget, it causes the error because each `Text` widget triggers `updateA(String name)` function.

It looks like every card is sharing one GetxController (getxA). Is there any way that to have each `Text` widget have its own GetxController? Or is it not possible in this case and I have to use the Stateful widget?

Comment: You probably want to use the [tag](https://chornthorn.github.io/getx-docs/dependency-management/instancing-method) property to create unique instances of the controller. However, it seems a bit excessive at the same time to have separate controllers for each Text widget. If you can share a fuller sample code, it is easier to review and suggest something.